# Understanding sheaves on normalisation of a curve: $v_* \mathcal{O}_{\tilde{C}} / \mathcal{O}_C$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves, curves-and-surfaces

Let $(C, \mathcal{O}_C)$ be a reduced irreducible curve and $(\tilde{C},\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{C}})$ its normalisation with $v : \tilde{C} \rightarrow C$. Then we have an imoprtant skyscraper sheaf $v_* \tilde{C} / C$.

According to **II.11** in *Compact Complex Surfaces* by Barth&Peters&Van de Ven, the arithmetic gena satisfies $g(C) = g(\tilde{C}) + \delta(C)$ where $\delta(C) = \sum_{x\in C} \mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}(v_* \mathcal{O}_{\tilde{C}} / \mathcal{O}_C)$. From this we can see that the sheaf $v_* \tilde{C} / C$ plays a role in describing the geometry of normalisation.

My question is, what can you say about this sheaf. For example, can you tell the way to compute the dimension? (In fact, this is a skyscrape so dimension is almost the all information.)

Comment: The dimension at $x$ is $|v^{-1}(x)|-1$ no ?

Comment: @Nicolas Hemelsoet: No. Think of a cuspidal cubic, the normalization is bijective.

Comment: @abx oh of course. Sorry for my wrong comment.

Comment: If $p$ is a singular point, and $v^{-1}(p)=\{p_1,\ldots ,p_k\} $, the stalk at $p$ of the skyscraper sheaf is $\tilde{\mathscr{O}}_p /\mathscr{O}_{p}$, where $\mathscr{O}_p$ is the local ring of $C$ at $p$ and $\tilde{\mathscr{O}}_p=\oplus \,\mathscr{O}_{\tilde{C},p_i }$ its normalization. It is usually easy to compute if you know   the type of the singularity  at $p$.

Comment: @abx I cannot imagine why $\tilde{\mathcal{O}} / \mathcal{O}$ is of finite dimension. The stalk at $\mathcal{O}$ is a rather big complex vector space and the stalk pf $\tilde{\mathcal{O}}$ is direct sum of several of them. But $\tilde{\mathcal{O}} / \mathcal{O}$ just factors out one $\mathcal{O}$. Forgive me for abusing language.

Comment: The normalization of the local ring $\mathscr{O}$ is a finite $\mathscr{O}$-module. The quotient is finitely generated over $\mathscr{O}$, hence over $k$.

Comment: @abx Why finitely generated over $\mathscr{O}$ implies finitely generated over $k$? In fact $\mathscr{O}$ is not finitely generated over $k$.

Comment: What I said is that $\tilde{\mathscr{O}}/\mathscr{O} $ is finite-dimensional, because it is a finite $\mathscr{O}$-module annihilated by some power of the maximal ideal.